# Backgroundworker access via sender parameter

Tags: c#, winforms, backgroundworker

There is a [Microsoft Docs example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-run-an-operation-in-the-background) which shows how to use a BackgroundWorker.  And in the sample code is this comment, followed by an access to the BackgroundWorker via a sender parameter:

```
// Do not access the form's BackgroundWorker reference directly.
// Instead, use the reference provided by the sender parameter.
BackgroundWorker bw = sender as BackgroundWorker;
```

What error or behavior is being avoided here?  And is this always necessary?  For example, if I have a background worker that I create apart from a form, will this still be a good practice?

Full example from the link reproduced here for convenience:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace BackgroundWorkerExample
{
    public class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            // Do not access the form's BackgroundWorker reference directly.
            // Instead, use the reference provided by the sender parameter.
            BackgroundWorker bw = sender as BackgroundWorker;

            // Extract the argument.
            int arg = (int)e.Argument;

            // Start the time-consuming operation.
            e.Result = TimeConsumingOperation(bw, arg);

            // If the operation was canceled by the user, 
            // set the DoWorkEventArgs.Cancel property to true.
            if (bw.CancellationPending)
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
            }
        }

        // This event handler demonstrates how to interpret 
        // the outcome of the asynchronous operation implemented
        // in the DoWork event handler.
        private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(
            object sender, 
            RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {   
            if (e.Cancelled)
            {
                // The user canceled the operation.
                MessageBox.Show("Operation was canceled");
            }
            else if (e.Error != null)
            {
                // There was an error during the operation.
                string msg = String.Format("An error occurred: {0}", e.Error.Message);
                MessageBox.Show(msg);
            }
            else
            {
                // The operation completed normally.
                string msg = String.Format("Result = {0}", e.Result);
                MessageBox.Show(msg);
            }
        }

        // This method models an operation that may take a long time 
        // to run. It can be cancelled, it can raise an exception,
        // or it can exit normally and return a result. These outcomes
        // are chosen randomly.
        private int TimeConsumingOperation( 
            BackgroundWorker bw, 
            int sleepPeriod )
        {
            int result = 0;

            Random rand = new Random();

            while (!bw.CancellationPending)
            {
                bool exit = false;

                switch (rand.Next(3))
                {
                    // Raise an exception.
                    case 0:
                    {
                        throw new Exception("An error condition occurred.");
                        break;
                    }

                    // Sleep for the number of milliseconds
                    // specified by the sleepPeriod parameter.
                    case 1:
                    {
                        Thread.Sleep(sleepPeriod);
                        break;
                    }

                    // Exit and return normally.
                    case 2:
                    {
                        result = 23;
                        exit = true;
                        break;
                    }

                    default:
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if( exit )
                {
                    break;
                }
            }

            return result;
        }

        private void startBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(2000);
        }

        private void cancelBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.backgroundWorker1.CancelAsync();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.backgroundWorker1 = new System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker();
            this.startBtn = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.cancelBtn = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // backgroundWorker1
            // 
            this.backgroundWorker1.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
            this.backgroundWorker1.DoWork += new System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventHandler(this.backgroundWorker1_DoWork);
            this.backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted += new System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(this.backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted);
            // 
            // startBtn
            // 
            this.startBtn.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 12);
            this.startBtn.Name = "startBtn";
            this.startBtn.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
            this.startBtn.TabIndex = 0;
            this.startBtn.Text = "Start";
            this.startBtn.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.startBtn_Click);
            // 
            // cancelBtn
            // 
            this.cancelBtn.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(94, 11);
            this.cancelBtn.Name = "cancelBtn";
            this.cancelBtn.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
            this.cancelBtn.TabIndex = 1;
            this.cancelBtn.Text = "Cancel";
            this.cancelBtn.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.cancelBtn_Click);
            // 
            // Form1
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(183, 49);
            this.Controls.Add(this.cancelBtn);
            this.Controls.Add(this.startBtn);
            this.Name = "Form1";
            this.Text = "Form1";
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }

        #endregion

        private System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button startBtn;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button cancelBtn;
    }

    public class Program
    {
        private Program()
        {
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not an answer to your question about the purpose of `sender as BackgroundWorker`, but I would consider using the `async`/`await` pattern for asynchronous programming and/or maintaining UI responsiveness. To me, using `async`/`await` is a lot more intuitive and much less work than creating `BackgroundWorker`s whenever you have an IO or CPU-intensive operation.

Comment: So it's a best practice related to winforms events in general, and does not explicitly avoid an error?  If you add that as an answer I'll accept it :)

Comment: The reference is to any object being sent to an event.  In this case "sender as BackgroundWorker".  You could access properties A backgroundworker is a separate process from the main thread.  You could access the background worker using this.backgroundWorker1 (instead of sender), but that would create a cross-threaded situation.  With a form and a background worker you have two asynchronous processes that would be linked.

Comment: It is (hopefully) a minor improvement, but if you decide to refactor the code then you have one less thing to edit.  Also note that the snippet does not require the worker code and event handlers to be members of the form class, moving it elsewhere is desirable and that got to be a lot easier.  The previous comment is nonsense.

Comment: @Hans Passant  Can you clarify the *nonsense* part in the *previous comment*.

Comment: @Jimi, There isn't much to clarify, of course you can access the backgroundworker object in DoWork.  You're doing it, sender and this.backgroundworker1 are references to the exact same object.  sender does not have magic fairy dust applied, such magic doesn't exist.  The essence of the question.

Comment: @Hans Passant  Well, also `this.[SomeOtherControl].[SomeProperty] = [SomeValue]` is a reference to the same Object anywhere you write it (in the context of `this`). But if you access the reference in a `DoWork` event... Someone may be wondering why you have to `BeginInvoke` to access `[SomeOtherControl]`'s properties but you wouldn't do the same to access the `BackGroundWorker` object, since it's declared *in the same place* (Yes, I know that `sender` is just `Handler(this, e);`).

Comment: Very low odds for that, BGW is a component, not a control, so doesn't have a BeginInvoke method.  Too much mis-information btw.

Comment: @Hans Passant  You don't necessarily have to invoke the object itself. You could invoke `this` and set the object's property using a `MethodInvoker`. Yet the reason why it's not needed is still in a limbo. I commented mostly because you're usually quite informative in your comments. In this case, not so much. Of course, everyone should read the manual, but...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Hans Passant pointed out, `sender` and `this.backgroundworker1` both reference the same object, and so do the same thing in the example.  The reason for the warning is so if a future developer edits the `backgroundWorker1_DoWork` method to provide a different sender, `sender` will still work as intended, while `this.backgroundworker1` might be accessing a backgroundworker which is no longer related to the method.